# i am getting a runtime error for a leetcode find lucky integer in array problem, it works fine in dev cpp but shows error in leetcode

Tags: c++, runtime-error

```
class Solution {
public:
    int findLucky(vector<int>& arr) {
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());
    int count=1;
    int l=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
        if(arr[i]==arr[i-1]){  
            count=count+1;
        }
        if(arr[i]!=arr[i-1]){
            count=1;
        }
        if(count==arr[i]){
            l=arr[i];
        }
        if(count==arr[i]&& arr[i]>l){
            l=arr[i];
        }
        
        
    }
        return l;
        
    }
};
```

Runtime Error Message:
Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x602000000090 overflowed to 0x60200000008c (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34

Answer (score 0):

well for a start this leads to UB

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
    if(arr[i]==arr[i-1])
```

when i = 0 you are accessing `arr[-1]`